# File.exists() sometimes wrong on Windows 10 with Java 8.191

Tags: java-8, windows-10

I have a bunch of unit tests which contain code like:

```
File file = new File("src/main/java/com/pany/Foo.java");
assertTrue("Missing file: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), file.exists());
```

This test is suddenly failing when running it with Maven Surefire and `-DforkCount=0`. With `-DforkCount=1`, it works.

Things I tried so far:

- The file does exist. Windows Explorer, command line (copy & paste), text editors, Cygwin can all find it and show the contents. That's why I think it's not a permission problem.
- It's not modified by the unit tests or anything else. Git shows no modifications for the last two months.
- I've checked the file system, it's clean.
- I've tried other versions of Java 8, namely 8u171 and 8u181. Same problem.
- I've run Maven from within Cygwin and the command prompt. Same result.
- Reboot :-) No effect :-(

More details:

- When I see this problem, I start to see the "The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?" in other projects. That's why I tried `forkCount=0` which often helps in this case to find out why the forked VM crashed.
- This has started recently, maybe around the October 2018 update of Windows 10. Before that, the builds were rock solid for about three years. My machine was switched to Windows 10 late 2017, I think.
- I'm using Maven 3.6 and can't easily try an older version because of an important bug that was fixed with it. I did see the VM crash above with Maven 3.5.2 as well.
- It's always the same files which fail (so it's stable).

`ulimit` (from Cygwin) says:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

I'm wondering if the "open files" limit of 256 only applied to Cygwin processes or whether that's something which Cygwin reads from Windows.

Let me know if you need anything else. I'm running out of ideas what I could try.

### Update 1

[Bernhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366169/bernhard) asked me to print absolute names. My answer was that I was already using absolute names but I was wrong. The actual code was:

```
File file = new File("src/main/java/com/pany/Foo.java");
if (!file.exists()) {
    log.debug("Missing file {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
    ... fail ...
}

... do something with file...
```

I have now changed this to:

```
File file = new File("src/main/java/com/pany/Foo.java").getAbsoluteFile();
if (!file.exists()) {
    log.debug("Missing file {}", file);
}
```

and that fixed the problem. I just can't understand *why*.

When Maven creates a forked VM to run the tests with Surefire, then it can change the current directory. So in this case, it would make sense that the tests work when forked but fail when running in the same VM (since the VM was created in the root folder of the multi-module build). But why is making the path absolute before the call to `exists()` fixing the issue?

Comment: 1+ for a good structured question IMO, but this is *really* hard to answer :(

Comment: Interesting. One thing comes up to my mind, although a bit unlikely, since it works with a different fork count: can you check if it's a problem of the capitalisation of the File name? E.g. that the file's real name is not foo.java?

Comment: Second thing - what is the return code if you do `createNewFile` on that file (after it told you it does not exist)?

Comment: @Bernhard Capitalisation is the same on disk and in the test. I'll try createNewFile().

Comment: Love this: `com/pany`

Comment: About capitalisation - on mac, the default setting is that capitalisation does not matter, and I once ran into a problem where IntelliJ displayed me a file with capital first letter, but on disk it was not. I had to look into the terminal to figure that out.

Comment: Do also print the absolute file name. Not sure how the forking works, but maybe it starts the process in a different folder, and then your relative path does not resolve?

Comment: @Bernhard I'm using absolute paths ... except in one place. I fixed that and now it works better. BUT the problem appeared when I **didn't fork**. When I was forking, it worked... I could understand when the forked VM was running in a different folder. But I'm using the same relative path and just call `getAbsoluteFile()` on it. How is file.exists() and file.getAbsolutePath().exists() different?

Comment: Yes, an extremely well-presented but puzzling problem. Does the system's application-event log contain _any_ clues?

Comment: @MikeRobinson I know very little about the event log. When a process runs out of resources, where/how would that be logged?

Comment: "How is file.exists() and file.getAbsolutePath().exists() different?" that is not different, but what I mean is, when you're inside of `/x` and do `new File("y/z").getAbsolutePath()`, you get "/x/y/z". But if you are inside of `/a`, then `new File("y/z").getAbsolutePath()` is "/a/y/y".
Can you just do a `System.out.println(new File("src/main/java/com/pany/Foo.java").getAbsoluteFile())` and check if there is a difference in the output depending on the fork param?

Comment: And do a `System.out.println(new File("src/main/java/com/pany/Foo.java").getAbsoluteFile().createNewFile());` before the assert, and also let me know what the output is and if the assert then fails or not.

Comment: @Bernhard See my edits. Just using `new File("y/z").getAbsolutePath().exists()` fixes the issue. Why???

Comment: Mega weird! But now it seems more to look like a bug in the JVM. Try isolating it and submitting it as a bug report to both maven as well as to the Java maintainers...

Comment: You have the same effect when switching the jdk and JVM, like, openjdk instead of oracle?

Comment: I think that `new File().exists()` and `new File().getAbsoluteFile().exists()` use a different source to determine the current directory.

Comment: It looks like File.getAbsoluteFile() uses FileSystem.resolve() which will call `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. `exists()`, on the other hand, directly calls a native method which probably uses the Windows API to get the file attributes via `java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes(File)`. That probably uses a field of the Windows process to determine the current folder.

Comment: The question is: Why are you testing files in `src/main/java/` if they exist? What should that proove/test? Or is this just and example of the pattern? Furthermore if those files are really java files they will be compiled and in the end available via the classpath. On the other hand you could get the correct location for the absolute path location via `basedir` system property which is injected by maven-surefire-pugin during the test...

Answer (score 8):

Some background. Each process has a notion of "current directory". When started from the command line, then it's the directory in which the command was executed. When started from the UI, it's usually the folder in which the program (the .exe file) is.

In the command prompt or BASH, you can change this folder with `cd` for the process which runs the command prompt.

When Maven builds a multi-module project, it has to change this for each module (so that the relative path `src/main/java/` always points to the right place). Unfortunately, Java doesn't have a "set current directory" method anywhere. You can only specify one when creating a new process and you can modify the system property `user.dir`.

That's why `new File("a").exists()` and `new File("a").getAbsoluteFile().exists()` work differently.

The latter will use `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "a")` to determine the path and the former will use the Windows API function `_wgetdcwd` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getdcwd-wgetdcwd?view=vs-2017)) which in turn uses a field of the Windows process to get the current directory - in our case, that's always the folder in which Maven was originally started because Java doesn't update the field in the process when someone changes `user.dir` and Maven can only change this property to "simulate" changing folders.

`WinNTFileSystem_md.c` calls `fileToNTPath()`. That's defined in `io_util_md.c` and calls `pathToNTPath()`. For relative paths, it will call `currentDirLength()` which calls `currentDir()` which calls `_wgetdcwd()`.

See also:

- https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/jdk7u6-b08/src/windows/native/java/io/WinNTFileSystem_md.c
- https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/jdk7u6-b08/src/windows/native/java/io/io_util_md.c

and here is the place where the Surefire plugin modifies the Property `user.dir`: https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/56d41b4c903b6c134c5e1a2891f9f08be7e5039f/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L1060

When not forking, it's copied into the current VM's System properties: https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/56d41b4c903b6c134c5e1a2891f9f08be7e5039f/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L1133

Comment: Not fully clear to me... Do you mean that the current directory may change during the run while "user.dir" property will not? "user.dir" is the dir where the JVM started from isn't it?

Comment: Does this mean that something somewhere is changing the value of the `user.dir` property in order to simulate changing the current working directory?

Comment: @StuartMarks Apparently. that said, I couldn't find the place in Maven's source code where it happens but `new File("a").getAbsoluteFile()` and the only difference that I could find in the Java VM sources is that this builds a path relative to `user.dir`.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I mean that someone must change `user.dir`, probably Maven.

Comment: @StuartMarks Added links to the source code where Maven modifies `user.dir` while running unit tests.

Comment: Surefire should not be changing the value of user.dir in a running VM as it can lead to unpredictable behavior. There is a warning in the javadoc about this. Also since JDK 11, all APIs in java.base that read user.dir, or other critical properties, will use the value of the property from startup, they never re-read the property. It would be interesting to know if there is a bug against surefire open on this already.

Comment: The code that actually sets the system properties does the obvious thing: https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/56d41b4c903b6c134c5e1a2891f9f08be7e5039f/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/SurefireProperties.java#L137   Also, the corresponding code in 3.0.0-M3 (which seems to current as of this writing) looks pretty much the same to my eye, though I haven't tested it on JDK 8 or JDK 11. Given the system property changes in JDK 11, I wouldn't be surprised if Surefire's behavior in JDK 11 is broken in a different way than on JDK 8.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for this diagnostic information. If Surefire is still relying on being able to modify `user.dir` then this is still likely to be a problem.

Comment: @StuartMarks I don't see a way to run per-module unit tests without being able to change the current directory. Maybe `user.dir` is the wrong approach but unit tests need to be able to access files using relative paths, otherwise a ton of projects are going to break.

Comment: @AlanBateman See `java.io.WinNTFileSystem.getUserPath()` (Java 8):        `return normalize(System.getProperty("user.dir"));` It even says there that this value must not be cached.

Comment: @AlanBateman Still works with JDK 11: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/999dbd4192d0f819cb5224f26e9e7fa75ca6f289/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/io/WinNTFileSystem.java#L349

Comment: I guess when you're talking about changes to the property, you mean stuff like this: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/999dbd4192d0f819cb5224f26e9e7fa75ca6f289/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/util/StaticProperty.java I think that code is wrong or at least dangerous. In every other language but Java, it's possible to change to a different directory. In Java, the FileSystem code uses `user.dir` for this purpose.

Comment: @AlanBateman Ah, sorry, I just saw that JDK 11 initializes the property when the class is created.

Comment: There is no equivalent of `chdir` in Java, this is something that has been discussed and rejected several times. Once you start to think through the implications of trying to do this in multi-thread app then you'll see what I mean.  The JDK has never supported changing `user.dir` in a running system. I hope Surefire can be fixed.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I think the comment "we must look this up every time" in the `getUserPath()` code refers to the fact that `System.getProperty()` does a security check based on the caller's permissions. If the value were cached, it might leak information to a caller that doesn't have permission to access the value.

Answer (score 1):

So I [have checked via printing out the system properties with some simple tests](https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee/commit/b51ccd76fd51e32ca7c3c360e6eba0bb4e451876#diff-e1a6958b3feca268fecd28f2e9aa9620).

During the tests via maven-surefire-plugin the `user.dir` will be changed to the root of the appropriate module in a multi module build.

But as I mentioned already there is a system property available `basedir` which can be used to correctly handle the location for tests which needs to access them via `File`...The `basedir` is pointed to the location of the `pom.xml` of the appropriate module.

But unfortunately the `basedir` property is **not** set by IDEA IntelliJ during the test run.

But this can be solved by a setup like this:

```
 private String basedir;

 @Before
 public void before() {
    this.basedir = System.getProperty("basedir", System.getProperty("user.dir", "Need to think about the default value"));
 }

 @Test
 public void testX() {
   File file = new File(this.basedir, "src/main/java/com/pany/Foo.java");
   assertTrue("Missing file: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), file.exists());
 }
```

This will work in Maven Surefire with `-DforkCount=0` as well as `-DforkCount=1` and in IDE's (checked only IDEA IntelliJ).

And yes that is an issue in Maven Surefire plugin changing the `user.dir`.

We might convince IDE's to support the `basedir` property as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Aaron, we develop the Surefire. We can help you if you provide the path for this:

```
assertTrue("Missing file: " + file.getAbsolutePath(), file.exists());
```

Pls post the actual path, expected path and **basedir** where your POM resides.
The theory would not help here. We are testing all the spectrum of JDKs 7-12 but we do not have the combination Cygwin+Windows which must be considered.
The code setting **user.dir** in Surefire you mentioned exists a decade.

Comment: Try with `File file = new File("pom.xml")`. You will get the root POM instead of the module's POM but `file.getAbsolutePath()` will print out the path to the module POM.

Comment: Or create `foo.txt` in the module `foo`. The error message will read: "Missing file: foo/foo.txt" but `exists()` will test the presence of `foo.txt` (without the path). Note: Only happens with `forkCount=0`.

Comment: Note 2: Surefire isn't broken, it's the implementation of the method `FileSystem.getBooleanAttributes()` in the VM.

Comment: Okay, JDK 11 decided to fix this by reading user.dir once at startup. So the code here doesn't work anymore when forkCount=0: https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/56d41b4c903b6c134c5e1a2891f9f08be7e5039f/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/AbstractSurefireMojo.java#L1133

Comment: JDK does not want to fix it. The issue was closed and won't fix, see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4117557

Comment: IMHO the Java is right. The `user.dir` is CWD and the CWD cannot physically change and so `user.dir` should not either.
The problem or advantage is that Java has an immutable `user.dir`. I wrote a project with two unit tests in my GitHub repository which explains wrong unit test and right unit tests, see https://github.com/Tibor17/surfire-io-java11
I hope we do nto have this problem in Surefire code.
In principle the user should read `file.txt` as follows: 
`new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "file.txt")`

Comment: If we support only `basedir` and avoid the changes of `user.dir`, it would imply what CWD is all about. I think the original idea of changing `user.dir` in Surefire was to provide certain comfort in user who writes the tests just once and run multiple times, where the tests could run in forked mode or in in-plugin mode without the need to touch the code. I admit the `basedir` is not compliant with IDEs and modified `user.dir` is in conflict with JRE perspectives.